# How to Update/Read a Collection Object Item Using Let/Get Property in VBA

Tags: class, vba, oop

this is the cls_Ativo class code so far:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private obj_Utilitario As New cls_Utilitario
Private col_Ativo As Collection

Private Const SQL As String = "SELECT tbl_Ativos.codigo_ativo, tbl_Ativos.especificacao FROM tbl_Ativos ORDER BY tbl_Ativos.codigo_ativo;"

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim registro As Recordset
    Dim campoRegistro As Field
    Dim i As Integer

    Set col_Ativo = New Collection

    Set registro = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)

    If (Not (IsNull(registro)) And (registro.RecordCount > 0)) Then
        registro.MoveLast
        registro.MoveFirst

        For i = 0 To registro.Fields.Count - 1
            Set campoRegistro = registro.Fields(i)
            col_Ativo.Add campoRegistro, campoRegistro.SourceField
        Next i
    Else
        Set col_Ativo = Nothing
    End If

    Set registro = Nothing
    Set campoRegistro = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set col_Ativo = Nothing
    Set obj_Utilitario = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Campo(arg_Item As Variant) As Variant
    Campo = col_Ativo.item(arg_Item)
End Property

Public Property Let Campo(arg_Item As Variant, arg_Valor As Variant)
    Select Case arg_Item
        Case "codigo_ativo"
            If VarType(arg_Valor) = vbString Then
                If ValidaCodigoAtivo(arg_Valor) Then
                    col_Ativo.item(arg_Item) = arg_Valor
                Else
                    MsgBox "O código inserido não é válido."
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "O código inserido não é um texto."
            End If

        Case "especificacao"
            If VarType(arg_Valor) = vbString Then
                col_Ativo.item(arg_Item) = arg_Valor
            Else
                MsgBox "A especificação inserida não é um texto válido."
            End If
    End Select
End Property
```

and this is what i want to do in the form module:

```
Private Sub btnTeste_Click()
    Dim obj_Ativo As cls_Ativo

    Set obj_Ativo = New cls_Ativo

    'Save a text into the collection item "especificacao" using Let property
    obj_Ativo.Campo ("especificacao","texto de exemplo, texto de exemplo...")

    'Return the collection item using Get property
    Msgbox obj_Ativo.Campo ("especificacao")

    Set obj_Ativo = Nothing
End Sub
```

when i call **obj_Ativo.Campo**, it just allows me to pass **arg_Item** as parameter and shows that it will not return any value, as if it were a Let property. but if it were a Let property indeed, it should allow me to pass the second argument as parameter.

what i want is to have a collection object in the class with all the variables with different types instead of private variables.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823367/let-property-of-vba-class-modules-is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-arguments

Comment: thanks Tim for the quick reply. do you understand what I intend to do? I want to avoid associating values to each variable of a class in the form, like: myObject.Name = "Tchutchu" => myObject.Age = 30 => etc... for associating values to a collection of objects dynamically by looping. I also want to append those objects in the collection dynamically. those objects will be the table fields. the controls in the form will have the same name as the respective table fields, so, I will be able to associate the collection objects with the form controls easily. do you thinks this can be done? thanks.

Comment: I see what you want to do: all you need to do is switch your `Public Property Let Campo(arg_Item As Variant, arg_Valor As Variant)` to a Sub like `Public Sub Set_Campo(arg_Item As Variant, arg_Valor As Variant)`  Your `Get` can remain as-is.

Comment: ok, Tim. I'll try this way. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would need a private collection variable in your class. I know that's not what you want to hear, but it's how vba works. You can't get/let with different types. Campo would need to accept and return a collection object as well.

```
private argItems as Collection

Public Property Get Campo() As Collection
    Set Campo = argItems
End Property

Public Property Let Campo(arguments as Collection)
    ' process your collection of arguments
End Property
```

You would interact with Campo like this.

```
Private Sub btnTeste_Click()
    Dim obj_Ativo As cls_Ativo

    Set obj_Ativo = New cls_Ativo

    Dim args as New Collection
    With args
        .Add "especificacao"
        .Add "texto de exemplo"
        .Add "texto de exemplo"
    End With

    obj_Ativo.Campo (args)

    'Return the collection item using Get property
    Msgbox obj_Ativo.Campo.Item("especificao").Value

    Set obj_Ativo = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this way but... probably it will be the best (and the only) way. c'est la vie (or such as life). thanks Ckuhn for the ready assistance.

Comment: @ThorMy It's certainly not the *only* way to do it, but from my experience with the language, I think it's your best bet. Good luck.

Comment: do you understand what I intend to do? I want to avoid associating values to each variable of a class in the form, like: myObject.Name = "Tchutchu" => myObject.Age = 30 => etc... for associating values to a collection of objects dynamically by looping. I also want to append those objects in the collection dynamically. those objects will be the table fields. the controls in the form will have the same name as the respective table fields, so, I will be able to associate the collection objects with the form controls easily. do you thinks this can be done? thanks.

Comment: I can't claim that I 100% understand what you're trying to do, but I can say with certainty that it can be done. It would be very similar to the `ADODB.Recordset.Properties` errrr..... property. In that example, `rs.properties` is a collection object which contains a whole list of variant objects. In your case, "properties" would be a collection of strings which represent properties in your class. I haven't really thought out how it would be implemented, but I'd love to know how it works out for you.

Comment: ok, Ckuhn203. I'll study recordset properties and try to get the result that I need to. if I have any doubts about recordset properties, I hope to count on you. thanks.