# VB: Assigning to a Boolean property in Adobe Illustrator, Photoshop

Tags: vba, vb6, photoshop, ui-automation, adobe-illustrator

While automating Adobe Illustrator CS3 using VBA I discovered that assigning a *Boolean variable* to a *Boolean property* results in assigning False always:

```
Dim New_Path As Illustrator.PathItem
Dim v As Boolean
' ...
v = True
New_Path.Filled = v     ' ERROR: New_Path.Filled is False
v = False
New_Path.Filled = v     ' New_Path.Filled remains False
```

Assigning to a constant works fine:

```
Dim New_Path As Illustrator.PathItem
' ...
New_Path.Filled = True  ' New_Path.Filled is True
New_Path.Filled = False ' New_Path.Filled is False
```

Verified for various AI Boolean properties such as `PathItem.Stroked`, `Layer.Visible` etc.

Verified for `Photoshop.ArtLayer.Visible`.

Verified for VB6.

So, I feel that this behavior is common for Adobe Adobe Creative Suite products.

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: try initializing it first: `Dim New_Path As New Illustrator.PathItem`. Can you try `New_Path.Filled = Cbool(v)`

Comment: Initialization is done well but not shown above - no worry about it!

Comment: Cbool works fine.  I wonder why it does while assignment doesn't.  And why assignment works for Office, for example.   Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: would you accept `CBool()` solution as an answer then?

Comment: Yes!  I feel it should be a common practice for automation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the `v` variable with [`CBool()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg278896(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: why (as it a boolean anyway)?

Comment: @Rob I could probably write a whole new article based off of that simple `WHY` question... Basically in VBA [the assignment to a LET property has  a weird syntax to it under the hood](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26488170/2140173). I believe (*may be wrong*) that what is happening here is that the `v` variable is being passed by a reference rather than by value. Casting it to either a literal True/False makes sure the variable is being passed by the value ( True/False ) and NOT by its address in memory (so it's not treated as a COM object).

Comment: Basically, you are passing the `v` to a LET property which accepts a `bool` type which is not equivalent of the VBA's native `Boolean`. It probably gets marshalled as an `object` by COM server and therefore direct conversion to a bool isn't possible. I mean this is just my *guess* - I would be more than happy if someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: So could just wrapping in ( ) do the same?