# Custom class declaration - definitions of property procedures for the same

Tags: class, excel, vba

I get what I can only assume is [this error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251357.aspx) (the error message is longer in Excel, but otherwise corresponds to the problem as described on MSDN) on the following code, and I don't understand why.

```
Private cLocation As String

' Location
Public Property Get Location() As String
    Location = cLocation
End Property

Public Property Let Location(Value As String, Value1 As String)
    If Value <> "" And Len(Value) > 2 Then
        cLocation = Value
    Else
        cLocation = Value1
    End If

    cLocation = Test.scrubLocation(cLocation, Me.NewZipcode)
End Property
```

It highlights on this particular `Let` procedure.

> The number of parameters for the Property Get procedure isn't one less
>   than the number of parameters for the matching Property Let or
>   Property Set procedure. Add a parameter to Property Let or Property
>   Set or remove a parameter from Property Get, as appropriate.

I assume this can't be it - `Get` has 2 less parameters than `Let`. Also, adding a parameter to `Get` solves nothing.

> The parameter types of Property Get must exactly match the
>   corresponding parameters of Property Let or Property Set, except for
>   the extra Property Set parameter. Modify the parameter declarations in
>   the corresponding procedure definitions so they are appropriately
>   matched.
>
> The parameter type of the extra parameter of the Property Let must
>   match the return type of the corresponding Property Get procedure.
>   Modify either the extra parameter declaration in the Property Let or
>   the return type of the corresponding Property Get so they are
>   appropriately matched.

Everything is string, so this should also be OK?

> You defined a Property procedure with an Optional or a ParamArray
>   parameter. ParamArray and Optional parameters aren't permitted in
>   Property procedures. Redefine the procedures without using these
>   keywords.

Nope.

I also made sure that I am not setting `cLocation` anywhere else. In the entire project, there is no other procedure making modifications to `cLocation` than the `Let` as shown above.

Am I doing the `Let` wrong? I was under the impression that I could have it done this way from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6643359/4604845).

Comment: If `Let` has 2 arguments, `Get` must have one, not none, per your first quoted section.

Comment: I did try to add an argument to `Get`, which did nothing. It was an arbitrary argument, however. Is there some "form requirement" for the `Get` in this situation?

Comment: It must be a `String` argument and have the same name as the first argument to the `Let` procedure.

Comment: Rory is entirely correct, but your code is a slightly odd use of `Property Let`. More common would be to run that `If` clause in the calling module: `If Len(val) > 2 Then obj.Location = val else obj.Location = val2`. And you'd only have the one argument in your `Let` procedure.

Comment: @Ambie I had thought of that already, but I want as much of the logic as possible contained in the class. `Value` and `Value1` are both existing properties of the class - the only reason I attempted to use the `Let` this way instead of using the same logic in the `Get` is because that UDF is relatively expensive and if avoidable I don't want it to run on every instance of querying `cLocation`.

Comment: @Ambie Your comment got me thinking and I came up with a more elegant solution. I won't post it here because it contributes nothing to the question I posed, but have an invisible upvote.

Comment: @Vegard invisible vote gratefully received. It's great this this site can provoke as much thought as it answers questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Get` procedure must have a String argument named `Value` too:

```
Public Property Get Location(Value As String) As String
    Location = cLocation
End Property
```